# Publishing Facebook Post using javascript FB.ui: embeding SWF not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash

After many attempts to use FB.ui (using the "feed" method) in order to publish a post with a embedded SWF file, I can't quite understand why it is failing to do so when using a self-hosted file.

Here is the fiddle:

- https://www.fbrell.com/saved/5c41ef7f33e3c432f3529b61e447aeb7

The snippet above works very well when using a link that points to a **YouTube video**, like this one:

- http://www.youtube.com/v/ykwqXuMPsoc?autohide=1&version=3

It results on a post that has a embedded/in line, playable movie.

However, **it fails** (it only shows a simple image as the attachment) when I change the **source** parameter to a video like this:

- http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-graph-api-post-to-wall/FlashMovieSample.swf

(Which, btw, belongs to this blog post: [Javascript Facebook Graph API: Posting SWF To Wall/Feed](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/04/javascript-facebook-graph-api-posting-swf-to-wall/))

I've also tried this with my own Facebook App, hosted code, and SWF file. The results are the same. The strange part is that the videos or SWF files work when used on the Open Graph meta tags (*og:content*). If I share a page with some video on those tags, the video gets embedded. This same video fails when used with the javascript API.

What am I doing wrong? Does Facebook treat the Youtube videos as a special case? Does it have anything to do with http headers on the (SWF) response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported this as a Bug on Facebook. They marked this as "By Design".
It seems they adopt this behavior to avoid "mix-content" warning on the browser, while treating Youtube as an exception.

From what I understood, there is no way to specify a "source" with an HTTPS value which actually results on an embedded/inline video.

Here is the bug report:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/589975484398226?browse=external_tasks_search_results_526fc388b99e18881434478